# Put a div to the bottom of a parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to put a div Element constantly on the bottom of his parant div.

This should work with

```
position:relative; 
bottom:0px;
```

Anyway it doesnt, the only think i can to is to margin top until it fits, but i dont like that. Can you find a reason in my code why the rlative position wont work?

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color:#999;  
}

#wrapper {
    height:40em;
    max-height:45em;
    min-height:40em;
    width:80%;
    max-width:60em;
    min-width:30em;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#333;
    border:#000 solid;
    border-width:thin;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#009900;
    border-bot:#000 solid;
    border-width:thin;
}

#content {
    position:relative; 
    bottom:0px;
    top:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:30em;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-top:#000 solid;
    border-width:thin;  
}
```

Content and Header are both parents of wrapper. So i want to put content on the bottom of wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Set the position #wrapper to relative, then set #content's position to absolute and bottom to zero.

Answer (score 2):

the parent element should have a `position:relative` and the one sticking to the bottom

```
position:absolute; 
bottom:0px;
```

hope this helps.